# How to avoid Network issues for SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, network

I have SQL Server 2012 and have setup AlwaysOn for High Availability. The infrastructure is on Azure VM's. After moving to this setup, we are frequently observing Network issues which either causes failover or secondary replica getting disconnected and re-establish the connection again.

We have worked on changing the default delay and threshold values. Which did not help us much as immediately after that we did observed failover next day.

Can anyone assist me on how we can prevent network issues to affect the Always on nodes.

Comment: What type of network issues are you experiencing? Outages? For how long?

Comment: Error 1135 - "Cluster node 'Node1' was removed from the active failover cluster membership. The Cluster service on this node may have stopped. This could also be due to the node having lost communication with other active nodes in the failover cluster. Run the Validate a Configuration wizard to check your network configuration. If the condition persists, check for hardware or software errors related to the network adapters on this node. Also check for failures in any other network components to which the node is connected such as hubs, switches, or bridges." Getting this error frequently.

Comment: For such error I am not aware what you can do from SQl Server side. Perhaps you should start looking at hardware and network level.